# broadcasting model changes

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set up a little POC to see whether or not angular would work for something I'm in the middle of.

I set up a REST server which I am able to CRUD with via angular. However, as the documentation and tutorials out there are so all over the place (read: SUPER inconsistent), I am not sure that the behavior I'm not seeing is the result of incorrect code or it's not something I can do like this.

I've gleaned from the docs that two-way binding is available, but it isn't clear how it works. NB I've read dozens of articles explaining how it works at a low level a'la https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693933/2044377 but haven't been able to answer my own question.

I have angular speaking to a REST service which modifies a sql db.

What I am wondering about and am trying to POC is if I have 2 browsers open and I change a value in the db, will it reflect in the other browser window?

As I said, I have it updating the db, but as of now it is not updating the other browser window.

### app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

var appMock = angular.module('appMock', ['myApp', 'ngMockE2E']);
appMock.run(function($httpBackend) {});
```

### controllers.js

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $http, $resource) {
  $scope.message = "";
  $scope.fruits = [];
  $scope.fruit = {};
  $scope.view = 'partials/list.html';

  var _URL_ = '/cirest/index.php/rest/fruit';


  function _use_$resources_() { return false; }
  function _fn_error(err) {
    $scope.message = err;
  } 

  $scope.listFruits = function() {

    $scope.view = 'partials/list.html';

    var fn_success = function(data) {
        $scope.fruits = data;
    };

    $http.get(_URL_).success(fn_success).error(_fn_error);

  }


  function _fn_success_put_post(data) {
        $scope.fruit = {};
        $scope.listFruits();  
  }

  function createFruit() {
        $http.post(_URL_, $scope.fruit).success(function(data){
        $scope.listFruits()
      }).error(_fn_error);

  }


  function updateFruit() {
      $http.post(_URL_, $scope.fruit).success(_fn_success_put_post).error(_fn_error);
  }

  function deleteFruit() {

      $http.put(_URL_, $scope.fruit).success(_fn_success_put_post).error(_fn_error);

  }

 $scope.delete = function(id) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want do delete the fruit?")) return; 
        $http.delete("/cirest/index.php/rest/fruit?id=" + id).success(_fn_success_put_post).error(_fn_error);

  }


  $scope.newFruit = function() {
    $scope.fruit = {};
    $scope.fruitOperation = "New fruit";
    $scope.buttonLabel = "Create";
    $scope.view = "partials/form.html";
  }

  $scope.edit = function(id) {
    $scope.fruitOperation = "Modify fruit";
    $scope.buttonLabel = "Save";

    $scope.message = "";

    var fn_success = function(data) {
        $scope.fruit = {};
        $scope.fruit.id = id;
        $scope.view = 'partials/form.html';
    };


      $http.get(_URL_ + '/' + id).success(fn_success).error(_fn_error);

  }


  $scope.save = function() {
    if ($scope.fruit.id) {
      updateFruit();
    }
    else {
      createFruit();
    }
  }

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $scope.message = "";
    $scope.fruit = {};
    $scope.fruits = [];
    $scope.listFruits();    
  }

  $scope.listFruits();
}
MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$resource'];
```

### list.html

```
{{message}}
<hr/>
   <a href="" ng-click="newFruit()">New Fruit</a>  
   <ul ng-model="listFruit">
      <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
        <a href="" ng-click="edit(fruit.id)">id [{{fruit.id}}] {{fruit.name}} is {{fruit.color}}</a>
        [<a href="" ng-click="delete(fruit.id)">X</a>]
    </li>
   </ul>
```

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FRUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUIT</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">NAVBARRRRRRRRRRR</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

          <button ng-click="listFruits()">ListFruit()</button>
          <button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel()</button>


                <ng-include src="view"></ng-include>          

        </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### form.html

```
<h3>{{fruitOperation}}</h3>
<hr/>
<form name="fruitForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="" ng-model="fruit.id" />
  <p><label>name</label><input type="text" name="name" ng-model="fruit.name" value="dfgdfgdfg" required="true" /></p>
  <p><label>color</label><input type="text" name="color" ng-model="fruit.color" value="fruit.color" required="true" /></p>
  <hr/>
  <input type="submit" ng-click="save()" value="{{buttonLabel}}" /> <button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Thanks for any insight or pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two-way binding refers to changes occurring in your controller's scope showing up in your views and vice-versa. Angular does not have any implicit knowledge of your server-side data. In order for your changes to show up in another open browser window, for example, you will need to have a notification layer which pushes changes to the client via long polling, web sockets, etc.

Comment: Right. I think I must have gotten confused with all the node/other stuff I've been reading. Angular only exists in the browser, so it's not like a model is shared between clients thus models won't be able to push out changes to all browsers...right?

Comment: Right. You can certainly make it happen, but you don't get it for free. Personally, I've been using RabbitMQ, and publishing notification messages whenever a model is updated so that any interested client can subscribe to those notifications and update themselves. Of course, the web browser can't subscribe directly, so this is done by the web server on behalf of the browser, and incoming messages are sent down to the browser via SignalR. If you're using node you might use something like socket.io or SockJS to handle the "live" communication between your web server and browser.

Comment: you can use Websockets to do the "push notifications" (socket.io in Node.js for example)